# Como puedo pasar código Mysql a Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, php7, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando en la ultima version de php, codeigniter y mysql. Quiero convertir mi consulta mysql a codeigniter

```html
mi constula mysql 

SELECT nom_eva, fec_ini, fec_fin, intento_max
from evaluacion
WHERE det_cur_sec='15'
```

Answer (score 0):

solo hay que agregarlo en el metodo select de la base

ejemplo:

```
$this->db->select("e.nom_eva, e.fec_ini, e.fec_fin, e.intento_max");   
            $this->db->from('evaluacion e');
            //$this->db->join('taclba2','condicion','inner');
            $this->db->where('det_cur_sec=15');
            $query = $this->db->get();  
            return $query->result();
```